# Research project: am I missing any verses where Jesus addresses wealth and greed?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospels, reference-request, money, wealth

This is what I have so far; have I missed anything important?

```
Luke 06:24-25 (woe to rich & fed) 
Luke 12:15-21 (rich fool parable) 
Luke 16:19-31 (rich man & lazarus) 
Mark 10:23-24 / Luke 18:24-25 (camel & needle) 
Matt 06:19-21 (treasures in heaven) 
Matt 06:24 / Luke 16:13 (god & money)
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: You might consider Matthew 20, the Workers in the Vineyard. While it's generally taken as a parable of heavenly rewards, you could also argue that the principles apply to wordly pay.

Comment: @GreatBigBore One methodology: [Biblegateway-Quick search: riches](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?qs_version=RSVCE&quicksearch=riches&begin=47&end=73); wealth & greed search yield no results.

Comment: If you are going to be talking about the Words of Jesus, make sure you address Isa 58- Jesus' message is heavily rooted in a preference for the poor, as even John the Baptist knew.

Comment: Also, even though it is Mary, the Magnificat (Luke 1) has a lot to say about the poor Vis a Vis the rich. I think a prof would find it relevant what his own mother was saying about him.

Comment: In general you should be focusing on Luke

Comment: @GBB- ",,,verses where Jesus addresses wealth and greed." Your title appears to equate wealth with greed. Is this what you meant? Do you also believe Jesus would condemn wealth?

Comment: @Hello I don't know about "believe" and "condemn". I have **read** the verses I indicated, in which Jesus pronounces woe on the rich and well fed, and delivers a handful of stern warnings about being enthralled by money (which I shortened to "greed"). I am simply wondering whether I'm missing any others that fit into that category.

Comment: @FMS Thanks, I had already gone through that process before I came. On the other stackexchange sites, you get quite a black eye for asking questions without doing some of your own work. I figured it would be the same here.

Comment: Isn't this a "list" question and therefore disallowed on this web?

Comment: @GBB- I wd say you are missing not just verses, but concepts too. To start with, in the rich man and lazarus, was it the rich man's wealth that was shown to be wrong in the story? If you read it over again, you will see that it is not. That is why I asked you if you were equating Wealth With Greed.? Are you, in your title? It sounded like it, and I don't think God would equate the two. It isn't Money that 'is the root of all evil.', but " The LOVE of money that is the root of all evil." These are two entirely diff. things. (That is a verse itself, a quote form the Bible.

Comment: Yes, as @Steve has said, this is what we would call a list question, which is very much discouraged across all Stack Exchange websites. It's just not a very good fit for this strict question and answer format. Please see [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409)

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a list question. List questions are not constructive within the strict question and answer format. Questions should instead be focused on specific issues that can be factually answered with a minimal amount of opinion and "polling".

Comment: @fredsbend My apologies. I try to stay within the guidelines; sometimes it's hard to remember them all. I'll re-read and try to do better.

Comment: @GreatBigBore No problem. I'm just glad to see you are trying to learn the site policies. Some new users just don't care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These all touch on the topic of greed, because they put money in their place.  The ones marked with a = I consider to be more so.

= Matthew 13:22..  the seed among thorny soil was choked by the deceitful ness of wealth.

Luke 16:1-12, Jesus refers to "unrighteous mammon".

= Luke 16:14 also points out sneering Pharisees who loved money.

Luke 21; Mark 10, the widow giving more than any others.  Many regard this as Jesus' last public teaching before the crucifixion, and it was on money.

The parable in Matthew 20 seems to be about generosity, but is also about the envy of gain.  Those given the same wages though they should receive more, but the focus was on the generosity of the master compared with the attitude and expectation of the workers.

That's it at a glance.  Some of them may not be exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully provide some useful ideas.

Additionally, it should probably be said that God no where says wealth is evil, merely coveteousness.  Merely reflecting on the Old Testament and the passages in the Gospels, God was upset when men valued wealth more than their brother. Things over people.  The material is not focus, the heart always is.  If the man in Mark 10 had seen the true worth of what Jesus was offering,  we might have read about an impromptu estate sale...  Perhaps this goes beyond simply answering the question, but it does seem to be "the whole truth".  It seems to round out the answer, keeping it in focus.

Comment: @Benj- I think your conclusions are spot on, but you may get downvotes for lacking some in construction. See what other answers do with colour, inset of paragraphs containing the quotes, etc. - I haven't taken the time to learn to do it, maybe you haven't either. The appearance of your construction could be better, ie. using the equal sign isn't the best,..let me know again where you found the how to's, I think they are near the intro and begin, or maybe search aids for writing answers, etc.

Comment: under "your answer" in the box, there are bullets to use, and numbered bullets, for 'lists' of things, but I don't know how they use the coloured inset of paragraphs. You can use bullets instead of = and there is also something that gives you a header to make the answer look more professional.

Comment: @Hello For the "colored inset", begin a line with the ">". For the header, start with "#".

Comment: I haven't used the bullets yet either

Comment: [Learn all the formatting goodies here.](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/editing-help)